# C# How do I call a method from another class inside of my interface without making the method static?

Tags: c#, constructor, interface, static-methods

I am trying to ping google to check to see if I am connected to the internet, and I want to implement this in one of my interfaces, but I am unsure how to do this as my method is not static. Any help or insight would be much appreciated. The concepts of interfaces are new to me, so any resources that I could use to understand them better would also be very helpful! checkConnection() was where  I was looking to start, maybe creating a constructor to instantiate the method? but I really am unsure how to implement this.
This is what I have so far:

```
public class ApplicationManager : IApplicationManager
{

    public void ManagerRun()
    {

    if (InternetConnectionCheck.CheckForInternetConnection() == true)
    {

    }
    else if(InternetConnectionCheck.CheckForInternetConnection() == false)
    {

    }

public interface IApplicationManager
{
    void ManagerRun();
    bool checkConnection();
}

}
```

I cut out most of my code as it isn't relevant to the problem, but the issue is that "InternetConnectionCheck.CheckForInternetConnection() used to be a static method but it is no longer a static method, as I want to implement it in the interface so that I can call it once, and then just reference it throughout the rest of my code, whenever I want to make an internet connection check.
This is the code for the check:

```
class InternetConnectionCheck
{
    public bool CheckForInternetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I think, either you're very confused about what interfaces are and why you use them, or you need to go back and rewrite your question. The way you are talking about an interface doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Note that your current performs two whole round trips to Google when only one is needed.  You're getting nothing out of the second check other than wasting a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I probably am not being specific enough and I am likely using the wrong terms here. I am using the interface for other things in my project, but I need to use my internet connection check here before I run the rest of my code, as the code is uploading things to the internet. I believe I need to create a constructor for the internet connection check? Does that sound right?

Comment: FYI - this is not "pinging" Google, it is actually opening an HTTP connection. If you want to literally ping, there is [a class for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> I want to implement this in one of my interfaces

Interfaces only allow you to declare what properties, methods, and events an implementer must have. An interface method cannot have a body. In your example, `ApplicationManager` needs to implement the `checkConnection()` method required by the `IApplicationManager` interface.

To call a method on one class from another, it must either be static or you must instantiate an instance of that class.

Generally speaking, if a method does not refer to any instance members of its class, it should be static (there's not much point of it being non-static).

A few other tips based on your code:

1. Your interface should probably be in its own file, rather than be a child of `ApplicationManager`.
2. `checkConnection` should be `CheckConnection` to conform with C# norms.
3. You can omit `== true` in a conditional and use `!` instead of `== false`, as in `if (CheckForInternetConnection())` and `if (!CheckForInternetConnection())`. Better yet, just use an `else` instead of testing for the false condition. (As @Servy pointed out, you're making two separate calls in your example, which is not what you want).

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the speedy response, I believe I used the wrong term here, as I am very new to coding. What I am looking to do, is use the InternetConnectionCheck.CheckForInternetConnection() method inside of my ManagerRun, but I do not want to call the method like that every time, I was looking for a way to make a constructor I believe? And then use that within the method to just call "ConnectionCheck" and see if it is true or false

Comment: @John with no constructor specifically defined, you can still use the default constructor as such: `var connectionChecker = new InternetConnectionCheck()`. Given your code, I would go back to using `static`, as you're not making use of any instance members.

Answer (score 0):

The method uses no instance state, so the method is *conceptually* `static`.

It doesn't make sense as being an instance method.  Making it an instance method would be implying that the method uses some state of the object, and requires anyone wishing to perform the method to have an instance of the type on hand in order to perform the operation, even though you don't actually plan to use that object for anything.